Checking if two strings are equal regardless of order
I'm doing this in FileMaker so I'm mostly wanting to know if the theory is okay.
I want to compare two lists (carraige return separated and I want to know if the lists are equal, the lists are allowed to be in a different order.
For example:
Style: Modern
Title: Administration

is also equal to
Title: Administration
Style: Modern

The lists could be much longer than that and jumbled.
I can easily get a numerical value of the strings which is the sum of each unicode representation of each character , e.g. those strings both equeal 3602
If I compare the numerical value and the length of the string, would that be enough to call the strings equal but in a different order?
The lists are quite long, I imagine the chance of the exact same set of characters (spaces included) being used in different words is highly unlikely?? Like clashing UUID's would it be essentially impossible?
For interest here is the FileMaker code to get the unicode sum of a string:
While ( [ 

//initialVariable 
charpoint = 1;
converttext = "    Style: Modern
    Title: Administration";
lengthText= Length ( converttext );
finalnumber=0;
texttest = ""

] ; 

//condition 
charpoint <= lengthText;  

[
//logic 
finalnumber = finalnumber + Code( Middle ( converttext ; charpoint; 1) );
charpoint = charpoint + 1
] ; 

//result 
finalnumber

 )



I am not familiar with filemaker, but the normal approach would be to compare the sorted lists

I'm going to sort the lists when they are added to the database and compare them that way.
Using gematria (As suggested in the question) doesn't work due to the following.

Anagrams could easily break it.

For example
Product: car

is the same as
Product: arc


Also numerically hello = devil and that will also make the proposition fail.


I've added the answer now above. Comparing sorted lists.

It shows how the proposition in the question fails. Specifically it answers: "If I compare the numerical value and the length of the string, would that be enough to call the strings equal but in a different order?"

Are you copying from https://community.claris.com/en/s/question/0D5Vy00000I4LUxKAN/is-comparing-two-strings-by-the-sum-of-their-unicode-characters-a-valid-way-to-test-out-of-order-lists?

I started here because I thought it would be better placed here. Then I went to the FileMaker community. So the other way around, I copied it to there. I got the same answer from both though, sorted list!

For future consideration: You never made clear lists of what? Is the pair of lines in the question a complete list, or is it a single element of a list?
